# Graph using adjacency list in Java

Tags: java, graph

This is the main code.  Here I'm joining vertices by edges.

```
node[] gra=new node[5];
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        gra[i] = new node(i);  //I'm allocating memory for all the vertices.
}
void add_edge(int to,int from)  //to represent the vertice the edge is going and from is now self explanatory
{
    node new_vert=new node(to); 
    node temp=gra[from];
    while(temp.next!=null)
        temp=temp.next;
    temp.next=new_vert;
}
```

Now to do this operation I'm using this loop in main method.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)  //For simplicity I have taken 5 vertices
    {
        int n=sc.nextInt();                     //N is Number of edges from the vertices, for example in figure for vertex 0 the number of edges are 2.
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            int to=sc.nextInt();
            obj.add_edge(to,i);
        }
    }
```

[image: Example graph]

Is my implementation correct or efficient enough so that I can use this code for further use?

Feel free to ask if you don't understand the code; I will try to explain.  I know I'm bad at explaining.  And please forgive my English.

Here is my node class

```
    class node
{
    int data;
    node next;
    node(int data)
    {
        this.data=data;
        this.next=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aniket, and welcome! Could you include the code for your `node` class? This would be very helpful in reviewing the code.

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall Hi Benjamin I just updated my question you can check it again.

Comment: It would be great if you could also include the context in which `gra` and `add_edge` are declared (i.e. the declaration of the enclosing class), for the sake of clarity. Right now, you can only guess that `gra` is a field and not a local variable from the presence of a method declaration directly after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your code rather confusing at first, but I think I now understand your intentions behind the code, so hopefully I can say why these intentions weren't quite clear from the beginning.

The main source of confusion is that, for each adjacency list storing the neighbors of a specific vertex, the vertex this adjacency list corresponds to is represented in two ways: First, through the list's position in the array `gra`, and second, through the first element in the list. But the second representation is counterintuitive, because you are placing the from-vertex on the same level as the to-vertices. Using the picture you provided as an example, it would be like saying "vertex 0 has edges to the following vertices: 0, 1 and 4". It would be more to the point only to store the to-vertices in the list without the from-vertex, because the relation between the to-vertices and the from-vertex is already represented by the adjacency list's position in the array `gra`.

And a few words about capitalization: Even though the Java compiler does not require class names to start with a capital letter, there are certain naming conventions which, if followed, make it easier for humans to read code. One of these conventions is that class names in Java should start with a capital letter. In your case, this would mean that the class `node` should be renamed to `Node`. You can see that even the syntax highlighter doesn't recognize `node` as a class name if it's not capitalized:

```java
class node {

    int data;
    node next;

    node(int data) {
        this.data=data;
        this.next=null;
    }
}
```

vs:

```java
class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data=data;
        this.next=null;
    }
}
```

There are other Java conventions, like naming variables and methods in camelCase (e.g. `addEdge` instead of `add_edge`). Also, you might consider using whole words instead of abbreviations, especially if an abbreviation doesn't really save many characters (e.g. `newVertex` instead of `newVert`, or `graph` instead of `gra`). As far as I can remember, most advice in this regard I came across suggested to avoid abbrevations, and I myself also find `newVertex` easier to read than `newVert`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Stingy I really appreciate it , yesterday someone all ready pointed about that capital letter convention and hearing same again from you, I think I should change.Thanks again man for such a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Use Java `LinkedList` class

Almost always prefer built-in data structures to hand-rolled. For instance, your insertion routine takes O(n) time while `LinkedList::addLast` takes O(1) times.

Also, use an `ArrayList` instead of an array to hold the lists due to problems with generic arrays in Java.

### Write a `Graph` class

A class offers a great opportunity to re-organize your code. It makes it easy to separate initialization and adding edges.

### Correctness issues

Validate the input to `addEdge`. Throw an exception if either `to` or `from` is not in the appropriate range.

### Style issues

- indent and capitalize properly
- write fewer comments: only when something need explaining
- write shorter comments: use sentence fragments

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Graph {
    private ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> adjacencyList;

    public Graph(int numberNodes) {
        adjacencyList = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>(numberNodes);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberNodes; i++) {
            adjacencyList.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidNode(int index) {
        return index >= 0 && index < adjacencyList.size();
    }

    public void addEdge(int to, int from) {
        if (!isValidNode(to) || !isValidNode(from)) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        adjacencyList.get(from).addLast(to);
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GraphRunner {    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Graph g = new Graph(5);

        for(int from=0; from < 5; from++) {
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
                int to=sc.nextInt();
                g.addEdge(to, from);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ThankYou Benjamin for all the effort you put in reviewing my code I really appreciate it , I will definitely remember all the pointers you gave me. Love Stack Exchange community.